# How to get the Tempo dictionary in JFugue 5.0

Tags: jfugue

Is there a way to retrieve an array of strings containing all the tempos supported by JFugue (ver 5.0.9) ?

At the moment i am typing them as literals in an array
`new String[]{"Lento","Adagio"}` but i wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MidiDictionary has a constant, `Map<String, Integer> TEMPO_STRING_TO_INT`, that maps tempo strings to the numeric tempo for each string. You could get the keys of that map.